# Can removing the internal hard drive help me recover my data?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup

My mid-2015 MacBookPro will not boot up, can I remove the internal hard drive and back up my data that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. Here is a kit that would get you a new drive and a sled to do data recovery on the old drive.

- https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015

If you just need the sled, that’s cheaper. Or you could pay a recovery service to do all the work.

- https://drivesaversdatarecovery.com/

For DIY recovery, Data Rescue is amazing and great value for what it does.

- https://www.prosofteng.com/

Comment: I would have gladly paid to have it done if they would started work on it today, but since I got all this we are backed up, its the holidays, take 7 days or more, my DIY self went to work. I ordered that kit you shared. Thank you!

Comment: I also used an envoy pro back in the day, works great with the 2015 ssd! If you used encryption it should simply ask for your login password when you connect it to another mac.

Comment: Good luck @Daniel you likely can get a good read and with ProSoft you can do a very low risk self rescue. I’ll edit my answer to help with that if you don’t know them.